# How to fix System.AccessViolationException encountered while using nwCreate

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-navisworks

We are using the NwCreate APIs to create geometry.  Our application successfully executes and generates the desired output on its first run, however on the next execution it throws an AccessViolationException error. This occurs whether we are using the same data or different values for the subsequent run.

Our code is based on the example in this blog post:
https://adndevblog.typepad.com/aec/2012/07/nwcreate-color-of-geometry-does-not-take-effect-on-cylinder.html

I have observed that if we remove this code to add the material color attribute, then we do not get this error.

```
LiNwcNodeAddAttribute(geom, _material);
```

I have traced all of the handles we're creating and verified we are destroying all handles that are created.

This is the full text of the error we're getting:
System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory.'

Has anyone else encountered a similar issue?  Can you provide any troubleshooting advice?

Comment: Hi, it looks this is a Navisworks question only, instead of the one that is related with Forge or Forge Viewer. The best for Navisworks API question is https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/navisworks-api/bd-p/600 . While let me try to help you here

Comment: so, based on my code in that blog, run twice, it will throw exception in the second time? or you have any specific code added? I can setup the environment to test, while it will be helpful if you could clarify the scenario, or better share the test code you are using

Comment: Thanks Xiaodong,  I created a post on the navisworks forum, and also included a sample application there which can be used to reproduce the error along with my source code.   https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/navisworks-api/how-to-fix-system-accessviolationexception-encountered-while/td-p/10940630

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the cause of this,  the spoolID was previously destroyed

```
            LtNwcData spoolID = LiNwcDataCreate();
            LiNwcDataSetInt32(spoolID, arr_spool_ids[i]);
            LiNwcDataDestroy(spoolID);

            LtNwcData constructionComponentID = LiNwcDataCreate();
            //this was the error, using spoolID here (it was already destroyed):
            //  LiNwcDataSetInt32(spoolID, arr_cc_ids[i]);
            //fix was to change to this:
            LiNwcDataSetInt32(constructionComponentID, arr_cc_ids[i]);
```